# Error in tests: attempted to handle `didSetProperty`...while in state root.deleted.saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am passing some models into a component, something like this:

```
//templates/index.hbs
{{user-list users=controller}}

//templates/components/user-list.hbs
<button {{action 'newUser'}}>New user</button>

{{#each user in users}}
  {{#if user.isNew}}
    {{new-user-card user=user}}

  {{else}}
    {{user-card user=user}}

  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

//templates/components/new-user-card.hbs
{{input value=user.name}}

<button {{action='save'}}>Save</button>
<button {{action='cancel'}}>Cancel</button>
```

The `newUser` action creates a new model on the client only, and commits it only if the user hits `save`. The `cancel` action on the `NewUserCardComponent` looks something like this:

```
cancel: function() {
  this.get('user').deleteRecord();
}
```

This works when I'm clicking around my app, but when I run through this user interaction in an acceptance test, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <admin@model:user::ember578:null> while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: name, oldValue: undefined, originalValue: undefined, value: }.
```

Interestingly, the test completes the first time it runs after I start `ember server`, but every time after it fails.